# MySQL: why is a query using a VIEW less efficient compared to a query directly using the view's underlying JOIN?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have three tables, `bug`, `bugrule` and `bugtrace`, for which relationships are:

```
bug     1--------N  bugrule
        id = bugid

bugrule 0---------N bugtrace
        id = ruleid
```

Because I'm almost always interested in relations between `bug <---> bugtrace` I have created an appropriate `VIEW` which is used as part of several queries. Interestingly, queries using this `VIEW` have significantly worse performance than equivalent queries using the underlying `JOIN` explicitly.

`VIEW` definition:

```
CREATE VIEW bugtracev AS
  SELECT t.*, r.bugid
      FROM bugtrace AS t
      LEFT JOIN bugrule AS r ON t.ruleid=r.id
    WHERE r.version IS NULL
```

Execution plan for a query using the `VIEW` (bad performance):

```
mysql> explain 
      SELECT c.id,state,
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.id)) FROM bugtracev AS t 
               WHERE t.bugid=c.id) 
       FROM bug AS c 
      WHERE c.version IS NULL
        AND c.id<10;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref             | rows    | Extra                 |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | range | id_2,id       | id_2   | 8       | NULL            |       3 | Using index condition |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t     | index | NULL          | ruleid | 9       | NULL            | 1426004 | Using index           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | r     | ref   | id_2,id       | id_2   | 8       | bugapp.t.ruleid |       1 | Using where           |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Execution plan for a query using the underlying `JOIN` directly (good performance):

```
mysql> explain 
       SELECT c.id,state,
              (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.id)) 
                 FROM bugtrace AS t
                 LEFT JOIN bugrule AS r ON t.ruleid=r.id 
                WHERE r.version IS NULL
                  AND r.bugid=c.id) 
        FROM bug AS c 
       WHERE c.version IS NULL
         AND c.id<10;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra                 |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | range | id_2,id       | id_2   | 8       | NULL        |      3 | Using index condition |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | r     | ref   | id_2,id,bugid | bugid  | 8       | bugapp.c.id |      1 | Using where           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t     | ref   | ruleid        | ruleid | 9       | bugapp.r.id | 713002 | Using index           |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`CREATE TABLE` statements (reduced by irrelevant columns) are:

```
mysql> show create table bug;
CREATE TABLE `bug` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`,`version`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

mysql> show create table bugrule;
CREATE TABLE `bugrule` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bugid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`,`version`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `bugid` (`bugid`),
  CONSTRAINT `bugrule_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bugid`) REFERENCES `bug` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

mysql> show create table bugtrace;
CREATE TABLE `bugtrace` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ruleid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ruleid` (`ruleid`),
  CONSTRAINT `bugtrace_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ruleid`) REFERENCES `bugrule` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask *why* about query optimization for a couple of complex queries with `COUNT(DISTINCT val)` and dependent subqueries. It's hard to know *why* for sure.

You will probably fix most of your performance problem by getting rid of your dependent subquery, though.  Try something like this:

```
 SELECT c.id,state, cnt.cnt
   FROM bug AS c
   LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT bugid, COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
              FROM bugtracev 
             GROUP BY bugid
        ) cnt ON c.id = cnt.bugid
  WHERE c.version IS NULL
    AND c.id<10;
```

Why does this help?  To satisfy the query the optimizer can choose to run the `GROUP BY` subquery just once, rather than many times. And, you can use `EXPLAIN` on the `GROUP BY` subquery to understand its performance.

You may also get a performance boost by creating a compound index on `bugrule` that matches the query in your view. Try this one.

```
 CREATE INDEX bugrule_v ON bugrule (version, ruleid, bugid)
```

and try switching the last two columns like so

```
 CREATE INDEX bugrule_v ON bugrule (version, ruleid, bugid)
```

These indexes are called *covering indexes* because they contain all the columns needed to satisfy your query.  `version` appears first because that helps optimize `WHERE version IS NULL` in your view definition. That makes it faster.

**Pro tip:** Avoid using `SELECT *` in views and queries, especially when you have performance problems.  Instead, list the columns you actually need. The `*` may force the query optimizer to avoid a covering index, even when the index would help.

Comment: Thanks! As it has turned out, my problem was related to MySQL 5.6 and solved by updating to version 5.7. With version 5.7, getting rid of the subquery -- as you suggest -- makes the (now fast) query actually slower. I don't have version 5.6 anymore to try it, too.Covering indexes actually improve performance my example (according to `EXPLAIN`). Overall, I think your answer will be more helpful to others than mine.

Answer (score 0):

When using MySQL 5.6 (or older), try with at least MySQL 5.7. According to [What’s New in MySQL 5.7?](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-5-7-generally-available/):

> We have to a large extent unified the handling of derived tables and views. Until now, subqueries in the FROM clause (derived tables) were unconditionally materialized, while views created from the same query expressions were sometimes materialized and sometimes merged into the outer query. This behavior, beside being inconsistent, can lead to a serious performance penalty.